# To detect 3D Real world object using .obj files

Tags: opencv, 3d, object-detection

I am currently working on a project for 3D- real world object detection using Opencv Python. I am trying out this problem using a .obj file which is an input for the code. The .obj file contains the shape of an object that needs to be detected. By integrating live feed or video feed into the code. Then by using any method needed to compare both objects appearing in the camera and an object in a .obj file. If there is a match then the detected object is bounded with a green box and other objects with a red box.

I calculated dimensions from the object in a .obj file. Then write a code by integrating the camera into the code. I filed at detecting the object in a video feed or live feed. If the object is detected then I want to calculate the dimensions of that object and compare both dimensions. If there is a match then the object is bounded with a green box.

My problem is detecting the object before calculating its dimensions. I have a doubt, is it a problem to calculate every object's dimensions and compare them?

Please clarify my doubt and how can I rectify my problem dn proceed with my work.

Comment: Halcon has a detection method for 3D objects from their 3D model. I can't remember in detail, but I think it really did this: Render the object in "every" size and pose and try to detect the contour(s). It is this function: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LjN0aiSFPv8 and this paper: https://iuks.in.tum.de/_media/members/steger/publications/2009/icra-09-ulrich-etal.pdf

Comment: in my own (successful) tests I've used STL files, I think they are similar to OBJ files and maybe Halcon can read them also.

Comment: please will u provide  your GitHub repository  link. To overcome your problem which we are facing

Comment: why do you *assume* that there's a github repository? code is not a thing that exists and needs to be found. code is a thing that needs to be written.

Comment: what are the step or tools or libraries  which u used in your task . can u explain for use